# Grails design question on linking a java src class to service

Tags: grails, netty

I have a socket program running along with my grails app. The question I have is, what would be a good design to get the data from the socket to a grails service class.

Incoming socket data -> Netty decoder java class(in java src) -> how do I get this to the service layer?

The bootstrap class kicks off the socket server bootstrap at a predefined port.

Thanks in advance,
Abraham Menacherry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the service classes in your Netty decoder class if you make it to a spring component, [here is a example](http://www.jboss.org/netty/community.html#nabble-td3474198).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The following link in Grails documentation was also helpful [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html)